# Mixing dependencies versions

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I'm starting to learn develop android apps.
I'm following a firebase tutorial, and I'm getting some errors on my `build.gradle` file.

Can someone please help me?

My `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.brunots.firebasetests"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation ''
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.1com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.02'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

These are the errors:

- All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
  specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
  versions 9.6.0, 11.8.0. Examples include
  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.0` and
  `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0`
- All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
  specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
  versions 27.1.0, 23.4.0. Examples include
  `com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.0` and
  `com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0`

I don't know where is this the older versions is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're using firebase-ui version 0.6.0 which is implicitly using firebase and google play service version 9.6.0 (read more about it at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases/tag/0.6.0). So, you can't use the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
```

you need to use firebase-ui version 3.2.2 which is using firebase 11.8.0 ( read more at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) like this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:3.2.2'
```

and you also need to use support library version 27.0.2 for firebase-ui 3.2.2 (look at https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/constants.gradle)

Answer (score 2):

Use  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin` in your build.gradle(project), then in build.gradle(app) add following firebase dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:11.8.0'}
```

because when you are using firebase, all its dependencies version must be same.
And for the second error, share what you want to achieve, as it is because of version differences.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the very end of your build.gradle (Module:app):

```
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.1'
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Android library versions are supposed to use the same version as your buildToolsVersion which you do not have included. For SDK 27 you should be using 27.0.3. So the android section should start with:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

and the included libraries should end with

```
:27.0.3
```

Comment: Not solved.I think i need to remove the older dependencies, but i dont know where this is declareted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that analising the dependency tree:

```
gradlew app:dependencies
```

so I saw that conflicts are transitive dependencies of `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:0.6.0`

then i use exclude on my build.glade:

```
compile ('com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

No more mixing versions :D

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    }
}
```