# Getting error while mixing dependencies versions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, multiple-versions

I am getting an error as seen below image [image: Error Conflict Image].

I have tried many links and checked out stuffs on stackoverflow and managed to resolved most part but not in entirely .Is there a easier way to resolve this version mixing part .

Below is my gradle file

```
    /**********My Gradle ************************/
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.company"
        minSdkVersion 15
        versionCode 8  //Update on store 25th may 18
        versionName "2.1"

        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true

    }



    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    /*buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }*/
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/jxl-2.6.10.jar')
    /*implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'*/

    implementation files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')



    implementation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    /*implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.0.1'*/
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is my Error Log :

```
 org.gradle.api.GradleException: Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.1.
    at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.checkVersionConflict(GoogleServicesTask.java:161)
    at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.action(GoogleServicesTask.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at
```

I have gone through below post and manage to resolve some error but not entirely 
[Mixing dependencies versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158936/mixing-dependencies-versions)

.

Please check out .

Answer (score 0):

All Google dependencies should have the same version.
Add the following to your App build.gradle:

```
configurations.all {

resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    if (details.getRequested().getGroup() == 'com.google.android.gms') {
        // If different projects require different versions of
        // Google Play Services it causes a crash on run.
        // Fix by overriding version for all projects.
        details.useVersion("15.0.1")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of your gradle dependencies:

```
// All com.android.support versions the same
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0' // Don't use variable versions '+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

// All com.google.android.gms versions the same
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' // Don't implement repos multiple times
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0' // Don't implement repos multiple times
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0' // Don't use alpha versions

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
/*implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:5.0.1'*/

implementation 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Few tips:

- Don't use alpha or beta version unless you know what your doing
- Don't use variable version names (26.+), use constant version names (26.0.0)
- Use the latest version
- Group same version dependencies (com.android.support)

Answer (score 0):

**To solve this error** , you need to use same gradle version for all google play services

**Its good to use the latest version (`Go to sdk>tools - Check the Google play services >Update it`)**

Well for your project you should use these gradles

**Google+**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:15.0.1
```

**Google Account Login**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1
```

**Google Actions, `Base Client Library**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1`
```

**Google Sign In**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:15.0.1
```

**Google Analytics**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:15.0.2
```

**Google Awareness**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:15.0.1
```

**Google Cast**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:15.0.1
```

**Google Cloud Messaging**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1
```

**Google Drive**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:15.0.1
```

**Google Fit**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:15.0.1
```

**Google Location and Activity Recognition**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1
```

**Google Maps**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

**Google Mobile Ads**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
```

**Google Places**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1
```

**Mobile Vision**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2
```

**Google Nearby**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:15.0.1
```

**Google Panorama Viewer**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:15.0.1
```

**Google Play Game services**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:15.0.1
```

**SafetyNet**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1
```

**Android Pay**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:15.0.1
```

**Wear OS by Google**

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.1
```

Reference 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in your dependencies you are using different version of google play services and firebase libraries

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
```

**Use the same version.**

Otherwise check this [official blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html).

> Beginning with version 15 of all Play services and Firebase libraries, version numbers adhere to the semantic versioning scheme. 
>   **Each Maven dependency matching com.google.android.gms:play-services-* and com.google.firebase:firebase-* is no longer required to have the same version number in order to work correctly at build time and at run time.** You will be able to upgrade each dependency independently from each other.

Update the google play gradle plugin version to latest version, currently 3.3.+.

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'
```

and update the **libraries to the latest version.**